# "Hide" functions in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am in the painful process of transitioning from MATLAB to R, and still coming to terms with not having a neatly arranged MathWorks website to consult.

When writing MATLAB functions, they are stored in a local drive and can be accessed in my source code (as long as the function is in the active directory).

When writing a function in R, I need to "run" it, so it is stored in the global environment, then I can use it. Surely there is a 'nicer' way of doing this, as I will need to refer to many, many functions. Can I seemingly "hide" them so I don't have to see them, but always know they exist?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `?source` .... ?

Comment: Create a [package](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/packages.html)

Comment: You can also create one or more `.Rprofile` files that get run from the current directory. See `?Startup` for many details and options. I believe RStudio uses a project system that may allow tailored `.Rprofile` files, although I admit to not being expert in the exact mechanism it uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`source('F:\\RWorkingDirectory\\my_functions.r')` or you create your own R package which is very easy to do with Rstudio.

Comment: For starters you could show some courtesy by mentioning that you took everything from others comments. Secondly, creating a package is not "very easy" at all.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean to take anyone's credit. I just thought by the individual visualizing the actual statement wrapped in code it would make more sense. And with the new updates in Rstudio if you can create function then you can simply click build and export as binary and then install through command line in seconds.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with taking from comments, even unattributed (if I wanted to post an answer I could have).  But I would encourage you *not* to encourage the OP to use absolute paths: setting working directory appropriately and then `source("my_functions.R")` is usually better .The only counterexample I can think of is if you want to store all of your functions and use them globally across lots of different projects; in that case though you might be better creating a package, in the long run.

Comment: @BenBolker actually [this has been discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) and it seems (judging by the most upvoted/accepted answers) that courtesy is expected in one way or another. People should behave decently in general, both in real life and on the internet.

Comment: Completely agree with your comments

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions. I have decided to set up an environment instead.

E.g.,

1. Set up R script with my desired function(s) called `MainFunctions.R`
2. Add to `.Rprofile`:

```
e <- new.env()
source("MainFunctions.R",local=e)
attach(e)
```

Now I need to simply edit this file, and not worry about having to load them in, or create a package.